# Escaping admin_url output being passed to js (esc_js vs esc_url)

Tags: ajax, javascript, escaping

I am now hardening my first WP plugin.

One of my buttons calls a js function which is making a POST against `admin-ajax.php`.
The non-hardened code contains the following:

```
onclick = 'kuba_postMyStuff(<?php echo "\"".admin_url("admin-ajax.php")."\""; ?>)'
```

[This](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13051) (pretty old) ticket suggest that `admin_url` output needs being escaped. In effect I have ended up with the following:

```
onclick = 'kuba_postMyStuff(<?php echo esc_js("\"".esc_url(admin_url("admin-ajax.php"))."\""); ?>)'
```

Is that a good practice? Is that a most optimal thing one can do in such situation?

Comment: `esc_js()` alone is enough, i.e. `onclick="kuba_postMyStuff( '<?php echo esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ); ?>' )"`. But I'd store the AJAX URL into a global JS variable and use it from within the `kuba_postMyStuff` function, rather than putting the URL into the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for clarifying! Regarding your advice... Nice that you confirm the conclusion to which I went in the meantime. Good practice here involves using nonce, and all nonce examples I found require using `wf_localize_script` - which is also convenient for passing the url.

Comment: Yes, in the past, you would use `wp_localize_script()`, but for passing generic data from PHP to JavaScript, [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) is now the best practice for that use case. More information [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/#more-information).

Comment: Many thanks. I believe I did things right after your guidance.